# Entity Framework inheritance Automapper issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I'm using separate tables to save my objects who inherit from each other. My setup is like this:

```
public class User : Entity { /*...*/ }
public class Employee : User { /* ... */ }
```

In the database this means that I have a table `Users` with an `Guid` as primary key and a table `Employees` with a column `UserId` as primary/foreign key. This part works. I can get and set entities using the Entity Framework context.

I also have the following objects and mappings:

```
public class UserDto : EntityDto { /*...*/ }
public class EmployeeDto : UserDto { /*...*/ }

Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDto>().IncludeBase<Entity, EntityDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>().IncludeBase<User, UserDto>();
```

When I'm getting my employees I sometimes get the error: `Unable to cast object of type 'MyNamespace.UserDto' to type 'MyNamespace.EmployeeDto'`. The error is thrown on the mapping line below. It's realy strange because the error is only thrown sometimes. I haven't found a pattern yet when it is throwing it.

```
public EmployeeDto GetById(Guid id)
{
    var dbEmployee = getById(id);
    return Mapper.Map<EmployeeDto>(dbEmployee); 
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that it throws when getById returns a User that is not an Employee. If getById can return Users you have to map to UserDto (which Automapper might map to a EmployeeDto, but is still a UserDto).

Comment: I've checked this. The return type of `getById` is of type `Employee` and the id I use for testing belongs to an employee.

Comment: Does it also happen if you explicitly set both type arguments?
`Mapper.Map<Employee, EmployeeDto>(dbEmployee);`

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Do you have any idea why this only happens sometimes? If you write this in a response, I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: I've done some tests and was not able to reproduce the problem. I only get the exception when I return a User from the getById method instead of an Employee. Could you add the getById method? I'd like to see its implementation. Maybe it's a problem when EF returns proxies.

Comment: What Automapper version do you use?

Comment: I was on version 4.0.1 but updated to version 4.1.1 because the error came back. So far so good with version 4.1.1.